# How to clip only some values of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, clip

I have an array `(100,72)` and I need to clip only the values ​​of some columns. For example, I want that only the negative values in the column from 15 to column 72 are set to 0
I have seen that using the `np.clip()` function it is not possible to do this.
Is there a quick way or do I have to decompose and reassemble the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
arr[:, 15:73] = np.clip(arr[:, 15:73], a_min = 0)
```

In general, if `cols` is the list of column indices, you can use `arr[:, cols]` to perform the operation selectively on the specified columns. Reference: numpy [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: This raises an error because the argument a_max was excluded.